# UIApplication has no member keywindow in swift3 Xcode8

Tags: swift3, xcode8, uiapplication

I write this code in xcode8 but i have Error :

```
 if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keywindow{
            let blackView = UIView()
            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

            window.addSubview(blackView)
            blackView.frame = view.frame
        }
```

but i have error that UIApplication has no member keywindow

what should i do !?

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of search at the end i find it how to solve :

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window {
            let blackView = UIView()
            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            window?.addSubview(blackView)
            blackView.frame = (window?.frame)!

        }
```

SOLVE:

> shared.delegate.window

instead of

> sharedApplication.keywindow

and

```
blackView.frame = window.frame
```

Change it to

```
blackView.frame = (window?.frame)!
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve : (Swift 3)

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let blackView = UIView()
            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

            window.addSubview(blackView)
            blackView.frame = window.frame
}
```